# Classes of (non-continuous) functions with the fixed point property

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, real-analysis, sobolev-spaces, fixed-point-theorems

Let $K$ be a convex body in $ R^d$. (Say, a ball, say a cube...) For which classes $ \cal C$ of functions, every function $ f \in {\cal C}$ which takes $K$ into itself admits a fixed point in $K$.

#### motivation:

Of course this holds for continuous functions so we want more general classes of functions. For $d=1$ we ask for extensions of the intermediate value function, and the first such extension known to me is a theorem of Darboux which gives the intermediate value function for differentials of continuous functions. I asked about extensions for Darboux theorem in [this post](http://gilkalai.wordpress.com/2008/08/20/two-very-early-problems-a-simple-solution-and-a-new-problem/), and Marton Elekes proved it for high dimensional cubes.I recalled the question again after hearing a lecture by Haim Brezis, where he described three classes of functions that satisfy the intermediate valye theorem for $d=1$. He has other results about when you can "hear" the degree of a (non-contiuous) map which seems very relevant. (See [Haim's publication list](http://www.math.rutgers.edu/%7Ebrezis/publications.html) for some relevant papers with Nirenberg, Bourgain,  Mironescu, Nguyen, and others.)

#### Warning:

The answer may depend on $K$.

#### Related question:

[Fixed point theorems](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/127045/fixed-point-theorems/127095#127095)

Comment: Another class comes from defining a complete lattice on K and taking a function that is monotone w/r/t this lattice. This has a fixed point as shown by the Knaster–Tarski theorem. Many functions can be obtained this way, but e.g. rotations cannot be.

Comment: If $h:K\to K$ is bijective and $f:K\to K$ has fixed points, so does $h\circ f \circ h^{-1}$. Non continuous bijection may still be reasonable objects to work with, but I have no idea about how to prove that a given $g:K\to K$ is conjugated to a continuous $f$.