# Generalization of Darboux's Theorem

Tags: gn.general-topology, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, real-analysis

**Darboux's Theorem.** *If $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ is differentiable and $f'(a)<\xi<f'(b)$, then there exists a $c\in (a,b)$, such that $\,f'(c)=\xi$.*

Does any of the following generalizations

1. Let $U\subset\mathbb R^n$ connected and $f: U\to \mathbb R$ differentiable. Then $\nabla f[U]$ is connected,
2. Let $U\subset\mathbb R^n$ convex and $f: U\to \mathbb R$ differentiable. Then $\nabla f[U]$ is convex,
3. $H_k\big(\nabla f[U],\mathbb{Z}\big) \hookrightarrow H_k(U,\mathbb{Z})$, for all $k$,

hold?

Comment: @MarkMeckes $\nabla f[U]\subset \mathbb R^n$.

Comment: Yes, I realized that silly mistake and deleted my comment just before you posted your response.

Comment: What does $H_k$ mean, homology or Hausdorff measure?

Comment: I think the third part is dimension of homology

Comment: Very nice question! Related MO question http://mathoverflow.net/questions/135946/classes-of-non-continuous-functions-with-the-fixed-point-property related blog post http://gilkalai.wordpress.com/2008/08/20/two-very-early-problems-a-simple-solution-and-a-new-problem/

Comment: @LiviuNicolaescu: Homology group. I mean that the first is isomorphic to a subgroup of the second, unless one can define a natural imbedding.

Comment: @smyrlis your beautiful question is (indirectly) a motivation to give the following two questions: Question 1) Let $X$ be  a topological space, by $CC(X,\mathbb{R})$ $(CC(X,\mathbb{C})$, we mean all functions from $X$ to $\mathbb{R}$ ($X$ to $\mathbb{C}$) which sendsopen con connected sets to connected sets, assume that $f,g \in CC(X,\mathbb{R}$, does this imply that $f+ig \in CC(X,\mathbb{C}$.Are $CC(X,\mathbb{R}$ and $CC(X, \mathbb{C}$, vector spaces?

Comment: Question 2(A Hilbert space analogy): Let $H$ be  an infinite dimensional Hilbert space: is there  a Frechet differentiable map $f:H \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$  such that $\nabla f[H]$ is not  a nice space (By nice space we mean "contractible or at least simply connected)? The motivation comes from the third part of your question and the fact that the punctured Hilbert space is always contractible.

Comment: Related MSE post: [Darboux's theorem of several variables](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/571108/darbouxs-theorem-of-several-variables). [Dave L. Renfro's comment](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/571108/darbouxs-theorem-of-several-variables#comment1298652_571108) mentions some references.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It turns out than none of the three potential generalisations holds.

Counterexamples for the last two questions are presented in the answer of Ali Taghavi, and in particular by function $f(x,y)=(\mathrm{e}^x\cos y,\mathrm{e}^x\sin y)$, as $f[\mathbb R^2]=\mathbb R^2\smallsetminus\{(0,0)\}$.

For the first question, a counterexample appears in:

[Solution to the gradient problem of C.E. Weil, by Zoltán Buczolich](http://projecteuclid.org/DPubS?service=UI&version=1.0&verb=Display&handle=euclid.rmi/1136999135)

where the author gives a complete answer to the famous gradient problem of C. E. Weil. On an open set $G\subset \mathbb{R}^{2}$ he constructs a differentiable function $f:G\to\mathbb{R}$, for which there exists an open set $\Omega_{1}\subset\mathbb{R}^{2}$ such that $\nabla f({p})\in \Omega_{1}$ for a ${p}\in G$ but $\nabla f({q})\not\in\Omega_{1}$ for almost every ${q}\in G$. This also shows that the Denjoy-Clarkson property does not hold in higher dimensions.

Comment: I didn't get why that function is being a counterexample for generalization of Darboux's theorem ! can you explainit?

Comment: @Ashkan  Are  you talking about the  function  in the  linked paper "Solution to the gradient..."?

Comment: @Ali Taghavi. YES , function with above property

Comment: @Ashkan  Very interesting question! If  I  understand  your  question correctly, you  say why  does  this  f  is  a  counter example  to the  first  part  of the OP's  question. yes? This  $f$ is a  counter example if  that zero  measure  set would be a  countable  set?But is  it really the  case?

Answer (score 17):

Consider $f:\mathbb{R}^{2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $f(x,y)=\mathrm{e}^{x}\cos y$ then  $\nabla (f)$ is nothing but
$\mathrm{e}^{\bar{z}} :\mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, with image neither convex nor simply connected. This gives 
a negative answer to the second and the third part of your question.

Regarding the first part I do not know the complete answer. But I can say only the following:
for every $V\in \mathbb{R}^{n}$, $\nabla f[U]\cdot V$ is  a connected subset of $\mathbb{R}$, because the partial derivatives satisfies Darboux theorem; hence they send open connected sets to connected subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Moreover, as a consequence of chain rule
$\nabla f[U]\cdot V$ is  a partial derivative. In fact there is no a hyper plane which separates $\nabla f[U]$.

So it is interesting to consider the following question:

*Let $A$ be  a  subset of $R^{n}$, such that $A\cdot V$ is connected for all $V$, does this implies that $A$ is connected?*

Comment: Consider the region $A\subset \mathbb{R}^n$, $n\geq 2$,    defined as the union of the closed ball of radius $1/4$ centered at the origin  with the annulus $3/4\leq \Vert x\Vert \leq 1$. It is disconnected  and  for any vector $V$ of length $1$ the projection $A\cdot V$ is the interval $[-1,1]$.

Comment: @liviuNicolaescu thanks for the example. However it can be shown that this set can not be equal to $\nabla f[U]$, when $U$ is open connected set. In fact  no sphere can separates $\nabla f[U]$. Without lose of generality assume the sphere which separates the image, is the unit sphere around 0. Let $a,b \in U$ and $\parallel \nabla f(a)\parallel <1$ and $\parallel \nabla f(b)\parallel >1$. Choose a unit speed curve $\gamma: [0,1] \rightarrow U$ which connect a to b and its velocity at end points is parallel to $\nabla f(a)$, $\nabla f(b)$ now apply  Darboux to $f\circ \gamma$

Comment: So it is natural to ask:"Let $A$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ which can  be separated by no hyperplane or sphere, does it implies that $A$ is connected"?