# Intermediate value theorem for the Jacobian determinant restricted to a curve

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, differential-topology

Let $f:R^N \to R^N$ be a differentiable mapping, and $J_f$ its Jacobian determinant. Suppose that $\exists a,b \in R^N : J_f(a)<0,J_f(b)>0$. Is it right that on every continous curve connecting $a$ and $b$ there exists a point $c$ such that $J_f(c)=0?$

Some discussions started [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/161397/jacobian-of-an-injective-mapping)...

Comment: What am I missing? $J_f$ is a continuous function on $\mathbb{R}^N$, so it is continuous when restricted to any continuous curve connecting $a$ to $b$. That curve is just the image of some continuous $\gamma:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}^N$. So $F=J_f\circ\gamma:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous and satisfies $F(0)<0$ and $F(1)>0$, so by the intermediate value theorem it must vanish for some value in $(0,1)$.

Comment: @JoeSilverman I guess some people by "differentiable" mean just differentiable, not necessarily $C^1$. Personally, I also disapprove such maps :)

Comment: @AlexDegtyarev Ah, well, if $J_f$ is allowed to be (mildly) discontinuous, then can't one construct a counterexample by taking a standard example of a map $f$ that is differentiable, but not $C^1$.

Comment: @JoeSilverman This I don't know, as for ordinary derivatives $f'(x)$ there **is** an intermediate value theorem, even without the assumption that it's continuous. (Don't remember the exact name.) So, the question about the Jacobian may be not as simple as it seems.

Comment: @JoeSilverman The only hope that I see is that the restriction of the Jacobian to a curve is some kind of ordinary derivative. But standard proofs of such things usually assume class $C^1$, so one should go all the way over the proofs to see of they work in the more general setting. Boring :)

Comment: @AlexDegtyarev: I think you were referring to a theorem by Darboux. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_%28analysis%29

Answer (score 2):

The answer is negative. To construct a counterexample I used Jan Maly's paper [THE DARBOUX PROPERTY FOR GRADIENTS, 1996.](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CBwQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fprojecteuclid.org%2Feuclid.rae%2F1338515211&ei=uNNGVJDlDoTlywPxqIGwDA&usg=AFQjCNEQW1m0hB1iwFuoJLAEjj1qEJeIdw)  
First let's consider 
$$
\varphi(x,y):= \begin{cases} \displaystyle \frac {2xy^4}{x^2+y^4} -x, (x,y) \ne(0,0); \\0,(x,y)=(0,0). \end{cases}
$$
We observe that $\varphi(x,y)$ is everywhere differentiable, $\varphi^\prime_x(0,0)=-1$, $\varphi^\prime_x(0,y)=1 $  $\forall y\ne0$ and $\varphi^\prime_y(0,y)=0$. Now let's consider $f(x,y):=(\varphi(x,y),x+y)$. It's clear that $f:R^2\to R^2$ is everywhere differentiable and $$
J_f(0,y) = \begin{cases} 1, y\ne0; \\-1, y=0. \end{cases}
$$
Thus intermediate value (Darboux) property for Jacobian determinant doesn't hold even on a straight line $x=0$.