# What is the fixed-point origin?

Tags: reference-request, lo.logic, fixed-point-theorems

There is a fixed-point construction used in *Anil Gupta & Nuel Belnap, The Revision Theory of Truth, MIT-Press 1993, p. 194*: Use only $\wedge, \lnot$ and $\forall$ as *primitive* connectives and quantifier. We concentrate upon the monadic case and $G$, $H$ and $I$ are monadic predicates. The formation rules for formulas $\alpha$, $\beta$ ... are as usual, except also quantification upon monadic predicates is allowed. $\alpha_I$ is a formula $\alpha$ which may have positive occurrences of $I$.

Take $I$ to be positive in $\alpha_I(x)$ just if any occurence of $I(y)$ in *the primitive form of* $\alpha_I(x)$ occurs within an even number of negations. Suppose that $I$ is positive in $\alpha_I(x)$.

**Definition:**

$G(x)\overset{Df}{=}\forall H(\forall y(H(y)\leftrightarrow\alpha_H(y))\to H(x))$

One can now show in a small fragment of second order logic that

**Theorem 1** (Fixed-point):

$\forall x(G(x)\leftrightarrow\alpha_G(x))$

**Theorem 2** (Least fixed-point):

$\forall H(\forall x(H(x)\leftrightarrow\alpha_H(x))\to \forall x(G(x)\to H(x))$

I understand how Theorems 1 and 2 are derived.

But what kind of least fixed-point is isolated above, i.e. who discovered it and who first proved it? E.g., it does not seem that all the conditions invoked to prove the existence of Kleene fixed-points are necessary. A useful reference for the question may be the following: [Fixed point theorems](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/127045/fixed-point-theorems?page=2&tab=oldest#tab-top)

Comment: What do you mean by "what *kind* of least fixed-point"?

Comment: @AlexKruckman See my reference to Fixed point theorems for a plethora of fixed point results.

Comment: I suspect that @AlexKruckman might not want to read your reference. Maybe you could make a self-contained question?

Comment: @AnthonyQuas Let me quote from the OP of my reference: "It is surprising that fixed point theorems (FPTs) appear in so many different contexts throughout Mathematics: Applying Kakutani's FPT earned Nash a Nobel prize; I am aware of some uses in logic; and of course everyone should know Picard's Theorem in ODEs. There are also results about local and global structure OF the fixed points themselves, and quite some famous conjectures.

.. there are plenty of FPTs out there that I have never encountered. I will post later if you do not beat me to them. :)

Comment: Yes, there are many fixed point theorems. The one quoted in your question is one of them. I still don't understand what you mean by "what kind". Do you have some kind of classification of fixed point theorems in mind?

Comment: No. As indicated by the tag "reference-request" I am interested in who first discovered the fixed point theorem I relate, or presented its proof.

Comment: Oh, well then you should probably say so in your question! The only question appearing in your post is "What kind of least fixed-point is isolated above?"

Comment: OK, I will edit that in. :)

Comment: The notation is a bit on the terse side. What is $\alpha_H$ in the definition of $G$? It lokos as if $\alpha_I$ notation is never explained. And what does $I$ range over?

Comment: @AndrejBauer $G$, $H$ and $I$ are monadic predicates, and one can generalize to n-adic predicates. $\alpha_I$ is a formula $\alpha$ which may have positive occurrences of $I$.  I edit this in.

Comment: Thanks. Just to confirm: $G$, $H$, $I$ are *symbols*, $\alpha_I$ is a formula, and $\alpha_H$ is the formula $\alpha_I$ with $H$ substituted for $I$?

Comment: The construction reminds me of the fact that the least fixed-point of a monotone operator  on a complete lattice is the infimum of all fixed-points of the operator. The positivity condition on $\alpha$ amounts to monotonicity, and the defining formula for $G$ literally takes the infimum of all $H$'s that are fixed points of $\alpha$.

Comment: @AndrejBauer The answer to your question is affirmative.

Comment: @AndrejBauer The Knaster-Tarski Theorem gets it, right? $A(J,x)$ is a monotone operator on the complete power lattice, it seems to me.

Comment: Yes, it's the Knaster-Tarski. Although, there we take the infimum of **pre**-fixed points. I wonder if your theorem goes through with that change (replace the $\leftrightarrow$ in the definition of $G$ with $\leftarrow$)?

Comment: @AndrejBauer Yes, one only needs $\leftarrow$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your fixed point theorem is a special case of the Knaster-Tarski fixed point theorem. In fact, we can improve your theorem a bit.

[*Note:* this correction has been incorporated into the question.]
First a correction. You incorrectly transcribed the the original text, which defines the fixed point $G(x)$ as $\forall H . (\forall x . H(x) \Leftrightarrow \alpha_H(x)) \Rightarrow H(x)$ whereas you omitted the inner quantifier and wrote $\forall H . (H(x) \Leftrightarrow \alpha_H(x)) \Rightarrow H(x)$.
Arguably the book is teaching some bad habits, I tell my students never to shadow bound variables like that.

Let me write $G \leq H$ when $\forall x . G x \Rightarrow H x$. The monadic predicates are partially ordered by $\leq$, and in fact they form a complete lattice in the sense that for any schematic formula $\Phi(H)$, the monadic predicate $G(X) \mathrel{{:}{=}} \forall H . \Phi(H) \to H(x)$ satisfies the conditions:

- $\Phi(H) \Rightarrow G \leq H$, and
- $\forall G' . (\forall H . \Phi(H) \Rightarrow G' \leq H) \Rightarrow G' \leq G$.

Furthermore, note that the stated positivity condition on $\alpha_I$ implies monotonicity of $\alpha$ in the sense that $I \leq J \Rightarrow \alpha_I \leq \alpha_J$. We may therefore apply the Knaster-Tarski fixed point theorem (which states that a monotone map on a complete lattice has a least fixed point) to compute the fixed point of $\alpha$ as the infimum of all the prefixed points of $\alpha$:
$$ G(x) \mathrel{{:}{=}} \forall H . \alpha_H \leq H \Rightarrow H(x).$$
The standard proof of Knaster-Tarski confirms that $G$ is the least fixed point of $\alpha$ (see attached formalization in Coq).

There is a slight difference between your construction of $G$ and the one we used. Namely, you took $G(x)$ to be
$$\forall H . (\forall y . \alpha_H(x) \Leftrightarrow H(x)) \Rightarrow H(x),$$
which is the infimum of all fixed points. However, since every fixed point is prefixed point, and the least prefixed point is fixed, it makes no difference which infimum we take.

For your entertainment, here's the formal proof, written in Coq. (It's easier for me to verify things this way than on paper.)

```
Section FixedPointTheorem.

(* We work with a domain of individuals U. *)
Variable U : Set.

(* The monadic predicates on U. *)
Definition M := U -> Prop.

(* We write H <= G as a shorthand for "for all x, H x implies G x". *)
Notation "H <= G" := (forall x, H x -> G x).

(* Consider a monotone transformation α on M. *)
Variable α : M -> M.
Hypothesis α_monotone : forall I J : M, I <= J -> α I <= α J.

(* Let G be our candidate for the fixed point of α.
   We are just following the usual proof of Knaster-Tarski here. *)
Let G x := forall H : M, α H <= H -> H x.

(* G is a prefixed point of α. *)
Lemma G_prefixed: α G <= G.
Proof.
  intros x ? ? Q.
  apply Q.
  cut (α G x).
  - apply α_monotone.
    intros ? R.
    now apply R.
  - assumption.
Qed.

(* G is a fixed point of α. *)
Theorem G_fixed: forall x, α G x <-> G x.
Proof.
  intro x.
  split.
  - now apply G_prefixed.
  - intro P.
    apply P, α_monotone, G_prefixed.
Qed.

(* G is below every fixed point of α. *)
Theorem G_least_fixed: forall H, α H <= H -> G <= H.
Proof.
  intros ? ? ? Q.
  now apply Q.
Qed.

(* The alternative construction of the fixed point. *)
Definition F x := forall H, (forall y, α H y <-> H y) -> H x.

Lemma F_iff_G x: G x <-> F x.
Proof.
  split.
  - intros Gx H P.
    apply P, Gx, α_monotone, P.
  - intros Fx.
    apply Fx, G_fixed.
Qed.

End FixedPointTheorem.
```

Comment: Many thanks! :) I followed your correction.

Comment: I found this, and hope it is of interest:

https://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/misra/Notes.dir/KnasterTarski.pdf

Comment: Yes, lots of proofs float around. The [original paper](https://www.projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.pjm/1103044538) by Tarski is perfectly readable.

Comment: I began reading it yesterday. :)